# Is there a way to connect google sheets with tableau?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, tableau-api

Hey i am trying to connect google sheets with tableau. Is there a we an do this. I see that here is a driver named RSSbus Google Sheet Source but its free version is available only for 30 days which is already over for me. Is there any other way to connect.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no native connection. However, version 9.1 of Tableau Desktop includes something called the "Web Data Connector" which will allow you to create a connection to almost any data that is accessible over HTTP. This can include internal web services, JSON data, REST APIs, and many other sources. Here is a great introduction to this connector: http://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2015/04/16/tableau-web-data-connector/

As per http://community.tableau.com/message/327560#327560, if you are interested, it is now part of the standard Tableau 9.1 beta. "Please reach out to your Tableau sales rep to join the beta for access to the Web Data Connector."

At the moment, the Tableau 9.1 beta comes with some pre-built web data connectors, including a Google Spreadsheet connector which uses OAuth2 authentication. But you can also roll you own if you are comfortable with JavaScript. Here is an example of someone that built a twitter connector: http://tableaujunkie.com/post/119681578798/creating-a-twitter-web-data-connector